# Home Assistant How to display under and over temperature in Climate card

Tags: yaml, iot, home-assistant

I have the code below but`temperature_high_state_template` and `temperature_low_state_template` temperatures are not displaying in the `climate` card.

error log

```
2024-01-18 12:49:21.372 WARNING (MainThread) [homeassistant.helpers.template] Template variable warning: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ThermostatOvertemp' when rendering '{{ value_json.ThermostatOvertemp}}'

2024-01-18 12:49:21.373 WARNING (MainThread) [homeassistant.helpers.template] Template variable warning: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ThermostatUndertemp' when rendering '{{ value_json.ThermostatUndertemp}}'

2024-01-18 12:49:21.376 ERROR (MainThread) [homeassistant.helpers.template] Error parsing value: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ThermostatUndertemp' (value: {"IP_STARSSI":-27}, template: {{ (value_json.ThermostatUndertemp|float) + states(afterburner_desired_temperature|float) }})
2024-01-18 12:49:21.377 ERROR (MainThread) [homeassistant.components.mqtt.climate] Could not parse temperature_low_state_template from {"IP_STARSSI":-27}

2024-01-18 12:49:21.379 ERROR (MainThread) [homeassistant.helpers.template] Error parsing value: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ThermostatOvertemp' (value: {"IP_STARSSI":-27}, template: {{ (value_json.ThermostatOvertemp|float) }})
2024-01-18 12:49:21.379 ERROR (MainThread) [homeassistant.components.mqtt.climate] Could not parse temperature_high_state_template from {"IP_STARSSI":-27}
```

basically I have a sensor `AFB_desired_temp`  which is my target temperature and I need to display above and below `AFB_thermostat_under_temperature` and `AFB_thermostat_over_temperature`

I have been following the doc [there](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/climate.mqtt/)

Can you tell me why it is not working ? everything else works fine

```
mqtt:
  sensor:
    - name: AFB Desired Temperature
      unique_id: AFB_desired_temp
      state_topic: "AFB/sts/TempDesired"
      device_class: temperature
      unit_of_measurement: °C
      state_class: measurement 

    - name: AFB Thermostat Over Temperature
      unique_id: AFB_thermostat_over_temperature
      state_topic: "AFB/JSONout"
      value_template: "{{ value_json.ThermostatOvertemp}}"
      state_class: measurement 

    - name: AFB Thermostat Under Temperature
      unique_id: AFB_thermostat_under_temperature
      state_topic: "AFB/JSONout"
      value_template: "{{ value_json.ThermostatUndertemp}}"
      state_class: measurement 


 climate:
    - name: AFB
      action_topic: "AFB/sts/RunState"
      action_template: >
        {% if value in ("0", "1", "6", "7", "8") %}
          off
        {% elif value in ("10", "12") %}
          idle
        {% else %}
          heating
        {% endif %}
      current_temperature_topic: "AFB/sts/TempCurrent"
      max_temp: 35
      min_temp: 8
      modes: 
        - "off"
        - "auto"
        - "heat"
      mode_state_topic: "AFB/sts/Run"
      mode_state_template: >
        {% if value == "1" %}
          heat
        {% elif value == "10" %}
          auto
        {% else %}
          off
        {% endif %}
      mode_command_topic: "AFB/cmd/Run"
      mode_command_template: >
        {% if value == "heat" %}
          1
        {% elif value == "auto" %}
          -1
        {% else %}
          0
        {% endif %}
      precision: 0.1
      temperature_command_topic: "AFB/cmd/TempDesired"
      temperature_state_topic: "AFB/sts/TempDesired"
      temp_step: 0.5
      retain: false
      unique_id: AFB_climate_control
      temperature_high_command_topic: "AFB/JSONout"
      temperature_high_state_topic: "AFB/JSONout"
      temperature_high_state_template: >
        {{ (value_json.ThermostatOvertemp|float) + states(AFB_desired_temperature|float) }}
      temperature_low_command_topic: "AFB/JSONout"
      temperature_low_state_topic: "AFB/JSONout"
      temperature_low_state_template: >
        {{ (value_json.ThermostatUndertemp|float) + states(AFB_desired_temperature|float) }}
```